# How to properly create card display like trello, Mongoose and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have no idea, I have tried everything.

I want to do so under the lists were added and displayed cards in order and displayed from ascending position.

I have to do it so that I can add drag and drop later. Which will work on calculating the average position of the item on which I place and the item with the index below.

I can not do sorting in ng-repeat loop because the index displayed later is not matched to the array element. I tried to sort in nodejs but did not sort as it should.

In the mongoose database, I did this:\

**list**

**   name: { type: String, maxlength: 20, required: true },**

**card**

```
var CardSchema = new Schema({
  list: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'List' },
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20, required: true },
  position: { type: Number },
  // description: { type: String, maxlength: 300 },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  active: Boolean
});
```

**console.log response**

I'm downloading cards through an AJAX query
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 4 more… ]

**console.log response elem[0]**

Object { _id: "59bfeea368054710181c0c0d", name: "ostatni", list: "59bbdf061ebcd215a4b7af63", __v: 0, created: "2017-09-18T16:04:51.457Z", updated: "2017-09-18T16:04:51.457Z" }

it looks at this moment like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XSVq.jpg

**index.ejs**

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
  <div id="tasks" >
    <h3>{{ list.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="card in cards " ng-if="list._id == card.list">{{ card.name }} {{ card.position }}<button ng-click="take($index)">HERE</button>{{ $index }}</li>
      </ul>
      <form ng-submit="addTask(list._id, $index, newTask)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="add a new task" required />
        </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller piece**

```
$scope.loadLists = function () {
        return ApiService.staff.list()
            .then(function (resp) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                    $scope.lists[i] = resp[i];
                }
            })
    }

    $scope.loadsCards = function () {
        return ApiService.staff.cards()
            .then(function (resp) {
                    $scope.cards = resp;
                // for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                // console.log($scope.cards[i].name)
                // }

            console.log($scope.cards[0])
            })
    }
```

Thanks !